# It is possible to do a Multiple Weibull regression?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-regression, weibull-distribution

I have a response variable that I would like to explain with several predictors. The response variable is all positive continuous data. Some of the predictors are discrete while others are continuous.

I plot the density of the response and visually these look very much as a Weibull distribution. In `R` I use `fitdistr` to get the shape and scale of a Weibull fit. I can also use those parameters to simulate data that display a very similar curve to my response variable.

Now I would like to do something like a Weibull regression (in `R` if possible),

y ~ $x_1$+$x_2$+$x_3$+$x_4$+$x_5$+...

Is this possible? How?

Comment: The density of the *unconditional* response reflects how the mean response varies with the regressors as well as the variation around the mean.  Thus, the appearance of a Weibull response does not imply the conditional variation will itself be Weibull.  (Indeed, it could be Gaussian for that matter.)  What does the distribution of the *residuals* look like when you do a quick and dirty ordinary least squares regression?

Comment: What exactly you mean by OLS regression? a linear OLS? or something else?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares

Comment: The residuals of a linear multivariate model are mostly positive (R^2 = 0.08714). And an histogram that looks like an exponential decay. is that what you were asking ?

Comment: It is impossible for the OLS residuals all to be positive, because they will sum to zero.  If your response does not appear to be a linear function of the regressors, then you need to handle that situation first before you worry about how to model the distributions of the errors.  There are several standard, flexible methods, including transforming the regressors and using splines.

Comment: @whuber the sum of the residuals is zero (almost.... -1.39111e-14). So , I'm not sure what are you pointing to..

Comment: If you have one response and several predictors you have *multiple regression* but not *multivariate regression*. That second term is used when you model multiple responses at once. There are linear models (i.e. linear in the parameters, not in the link) with Weibull response -- they're widely used in survival modelling (though I've used them for other purposes, including ones with no censoring). However, as whuber points out, having a marginal response that looks Weibull does not itself imply you need Weibull regression (which is conditionally Weibull not marginally Weibull).

Comment: @Glen_b you are correct, it is a multiple regression. I'm still unclear on how to do the fit...  As far as I know in survival analysis the y variable represents  a vector of times and a vector indicating which times are observed and censored... which I'm not sure it is the case....

Comment: If you have no censored values all your values are uncensored -- and in place of times you just have whatever your response is. But don't bother with it until it's clear you actually need it... I've seen nothing to suggest that you do.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks, I will try to figure out how to do the "un-censoring" on all my data. I'm still unclear on the details.
On the other side. If using a weibull regression is a bad idea, the worst that can happen is that the fit is going to be horrible, right? 
I'm not sure why you think I don't need it, also If you think that I need to try other types of regresison I would like to hear your suggestions

Comment: You simply treat every observation as complete (as a "death" in survival analysis), so in the coding for whether each observation is observed until death or is censored, they're all observed until death. As for why you may not need Weibull regression, both myself and whuber have explained it. You're looking at the *marginal* distribution of the response (e.g. doing a histogram of the response, no matter what the values of $x_1$, $x_2$ etc, but the assumption relating to the response distribution in regression doesn't relate to that. The regression model relates to the conditional distribution

Comment: So the fact that the data looked Weibull to you is utterly irrelevant. The conditional distribution may look nothing like that.